# Select data after row with specific value

Tags: sql-server

Main problem is selecting rows after `Start Balance = 0`. 
Here is my code:

```
 Select distinct 
    st.date as [Date Incurred],
    ss.brkr_id as [Broker ID],
    ss.period_id as [Period ID],
    case when ss.debt_typ = 'Starting Balance' then sum(st.money_amt) else 0 end as [Starting Balance]
    case when ss.debt_typ = 'Balance' then sum(st.money_amt) else 0 end as [Balance]
    case when ss.debt_typ = 'End Balance' then sum(st.money_amt) else 0 end as [End Balance]
    into #temp1
    from debt_t st
    inner join debt_info ss
    on ss.period_id = st.period_id
    where brkr_id = '754234'
    and st.money_amt >0.00
    group by 
    st.date as [Date Incurred],
    ss.brkr_id as [Broker ID],
    ss.period_id as [Period ID]

select Date_Incurred,
Broker_ID,
Period_ID
max(Starting_Balance) as [Start Balance]
max(Balance) as [Current Balance]
max(End Balance) as [End Balance]
from #Temp1
group by 
Date_Incurred,
Broker_ID,
Period_ID
```

This brings back this result set which brings me closer to what I want but not quite what I want to show. This shows all the history for this Broker I only want to show information from when the latest Start Balance is 0.00. So once the
Ending Debt has been paid e.g 0.00 I don't want to see that. I only want to see open debts. From the latest Start Balance of 0.00 up to today.

```
 Date_Incurred  BrokerID Period_ID  Start Balance   Balance Ending Debt Amount
  12/31/2015    754234     1          200              300         500
  1/15/2016     754234     2          500               0          500
  1/31/2016     754234     3          500             -500          0
  8/31/2016     754234     4           0               1200        1200
  9/15/2016     754234     5          1200             120         1320
  9/30/2016     754234     6          1320              0          1320
  10/15/2016    754234     7          1320              0          1320
  10/31/2016    754234     8          1320              0          1320
  11/15/2016    754234     9          1320            -320         1000
  11/30/2016    754234     10         1000             1500        2500
  12/15/2016    754234     11         2500              0          500
  12/31/2016    754234     12         2500             500         3000
```

So below is the result set I am looking to return all information between the latest Start Balance of 0.00 up to today.

```
 Date_Incurred  BrokerID Period_ID  Start Balance   Balance Ending Debt Amount
  8/31/2016     754234     4           0               1200        1200
  9/15/2016     754234     5          1200             120         1320
  9/30/2016     754234     6          1320              0          1320
  10/15/2016    754234     7          1320              0          1320
  10/31/2016    754234     8          1320              0          1320
  11/15/2016    754234     9          1320            -320         1000
  11/30/2016    754234     10         1000             1500        2500
  12/15/2016    754234     11         2500              0          500
  12/31/2016    754234     12         2500             500         3000
```

Comment: Can the start balance ever be zero more than once?

Comment: Yes it can be 0.00 more than once I only want to see from the latest 0.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Suggestion is to add column belong to row number in temporary table.
 
You can select number of row that contain `Start Balance` equal zero then select `rows` greater than this row.

```
-- Define #temp1 tabel 
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp1

create table #temp1 
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,--colum belong to row number
    DateIncurred int,
    PeriodID int,
    StartingBalance varchar (200),
    Balance varchar (200),
    EndBalance varchar (200)
)

INSERT INTO #temp1 (DateIncurred, PeriodID, StartingBalance, Balance, EndBalance)

 Select distinct 
    st.date as [Date Incurred],
    ss.brkr_id as [Broker ID],
    ss.period_id as [Period ID],
    case when ss.debt_typ = 'Starting Balance' then sum(st.money_amt) else 0 end as [Starting Balance]
    case when ss.debt_typ = 'Balance' then sum(st.money_amt) else 0 end as [Balance]
    case when ss.debt_typ = 'End Balance' then sum(st.money_amt) else 0 end as [End Balance]
    --into #temp1
    from debt_t st
    inner join debt_info ss
    on ss.period_id = st.period_id
    where brkr_id = '754234'
    and st.money_amt >0.00
    group by 
    st.date as [Date Incurred],
    ss.brkr_id as [Broker ID],
    ss.period_id as [Period ID]
```

Here select number of row equal to zero.

```
select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS [Row number]
Date_Incurred,
Broker_ID,
Period_ID
max(Starting_Balance) as [Start Balance]
max(Balance) as [Current Balance]
max(End Balance) as [End Balance]
from #Temp1
where max(Starting_Balance) = 0
group by 
Date_Incurred,
Broker_ID,
Period_ID
```

You can select row greater than that row.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am reading your question incorrectly, you should be able to just add a `WHERE` clause which restricts to dates incurred which are greater than or equal to the date where the start balance appears as zero.  Note that in the query below I use `TOP 1` in the subquery as a precaution should more than one record have a start balance of zero.  In such a case, you might need to give us additional logic for how to handle it.

```
SELECT Date_Incurred,
       Broker_ID,
       Period_ID,
       MAX(Starting_Balance) AS [Start Balance],
       MAX(Balance) AS [Current Balance],
       MAX(End Balance) AS [End Balance]
FROM #Temp1
WHERE Date_Incurred >= (SELECT TOP 1 Date_Incurred FROM #Temp1
                        GROUP BY Date_Incurred, Broker_ID, Period_ID
                        HAVING MAX(Starting_Balance) = 0
                        ORDER BY Date_Incurred DESC)
GROUP BY Date_Incurred,
         Broker_ID,
         Period_ID
```